# How to install my node.js CLI on my localhost

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

So, I'm crazy excited I made my first Command Line Tool. Now, I'm kinda tired of typing `node tool.js command --option`. Can I actually install my single node.js file on my localhost or alias a command to it?

I built it with commander.js by the way. Super useful module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy if you've published it to npm.

Add

```
#! /usr/local/bin/node
```

to the top of your file, add the main file to your package.json

```
"main": "index.js"
```

and install it globally with

```
npm i -g <package name>
```

You can then run it with

```
<package name> command --option
```

Comment: Hmmm... it uses some environment variables to connect to my database. I wonder if I could write a 'login' command. I'm not doing any prompting yet, so that feels like a big next step.

Comment: Check out [inquirer](https://github.com/sboudrias/Inquirer.js), you'll love it! @Costa